# EC2 instance rebooting after stop

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance that I'm trying to stop by going to `Running instances -> Actions -> Instance State -> Stop` but after a few minutes it starts automatically. Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure it's the same actual instance, and not a replacement (autoscaling group?)  Either way, try checking the Cloudtrail logs to see if something's making an API call to start the instance.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion (you should post it as an answer so I can accept it). It was indeed an API call that started the instance.

Comment: I had a similar issue and realized my EC2 instance was part of an ASG, and the ASG was restarting a new EC2 instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recapitulating my prior comment, AWS will not restart a stopped instance on its own.  AWS Cloudtrail is the place to look for who/what made the API call to restart the instance.

Comment: For me to temporarily shut them down I had to: In the Autoscaling Groups I set the "desired instances" and "min instances" to zero. All affected instances were shut down.